# Android: How to lock screen orientation if I have 2 layout files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

In my application I have a layout-port and layout folder. When on Tablet device I only want my app to use the layout folder (lock it to landscape) and when using a phone (lock it to portrait) it should use the layouts that I specified in the layout-port folder. Somehow I can't get this to work.

In code I set this after I set the setContentView (also tested it before):

```
int screenLayout = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
        boolean isScreenLarge = (screenLayout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
        boolean isScreenXlarge = (screenLayout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);

        landscape = (isScreenLarge || isScreenXlarge);

        if (landscape) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
```

I also tried to lock the orientation in landscape mode in the manifest, but it still rotates:
`android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Any suggestions on how I can lock the rotation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On my device (phone with KitKat) setting android:screenOrientation="landscape" under <activity/> in manifest works as expected - layout from layout folder is visible. Can you share more details?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found a solution, I used 'screenOrientation= "locked"' together with the above code and it seemed to solve the issue I had.